# Avoid postback when button is clicked in asp.net webform

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, postback

I have FAQ page where recent FAQ are listed and one can search through the FAQ and also ask question etc...

I am able to list FAQ's using jquery ajax and i am try to search through the FAQ using jquery Ajax.

Problem i am facing is that when i click the Search button it gets postback. While i need to hide the current fAQ and show the once which match the search criteria.  In my case post back happen every time i click the search button and page get loaded every time.

How can i avoid post back and get data using the search function. Not sure where i am doing wrong.

Example with JS code on fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/thosoeuz/4/

I am using asp.net webform for this project.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchQA" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><asp:Button ID="btnSearchQA" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="SEARCH" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="triggerSearch();" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/></span>
</div>
<div class="row-qa-col-wrapper">
    <!-- QA WRapper-->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    </div>
    <p id="loadmore">Load More...</p>
    <div class="row loader-wrapper"><img id="loader" class="news-loading" alt="" src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/images/loading/30.gif") %>' style="display:none" /></div>
    <!-- QA WRapper end-->
</div>
```

**JS PART OF CODE**

```
//CODE FOR SEARCH BUTTON

 function triggerSearch() {
   var vSearch = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSearchQA').value;
   // alert(vsearch.length );
   var vSearchLength = vSearch.length;

   if (vSearchLength > 0) {
     $(".panel-default").css("display", "none");
     SearchRecords(vSearch);
   } else {
     alert('Null')
   }
 }


 // search Q&A
 var pageIndex2 = 0;
 var pageCount2;

 function SearchRecords(vSearch) {
   pageIndex2++;
   //Hide Default panel and show search result
   // $(".panel-default").hide();



   if (pageIndex2 == 1 || pageIndex2 <= pageCount2) {
     $("#loader").show();
     $("#loadmore").show();
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<%= ResolveUrl ("~/en/QAForm.aspx / SearchQuestions ") %>",
       //data: JSON.stringify('{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + ', Keyword: zakat}'),
       data: JSON.stringify({
         pageIndex: pageIndex,
         Keyword: vSearch
       }),
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: ShowSearchResult,
       failure: function(response) {
         alert(response.d);
       },
       error: function(response) {
         alert(response.d);
       }
     });
   }
 }

 //For Search
 function ShowSearchResult(response) {
   //Hide Default panel and show search result
   // $(".panel-default").hide();

   var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
   var xml = $(xmlDoc);
   pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());

   //Record Count for search
   var RowCount = parseInt(xml.find("RowCount").eq(0).find("RowCount").text());
   //alert('RowCount' + RowCount);

   var news = xml.find("Table");
   var ctr = 0
   news.each(function() {
     var newsItem = $(this);
     ctr = ctr + 100;
     var vQuestion = newsItem.find("Question").text();

     var vAnswer = newsItem.find("Answer").text();
     var newsDate = newsItem.find("ReleaseDate").text();
     // var newsHijriDate = newsItem.find("NewsBrief").text();

     $('<div class="panel panel-info panel-search"><div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse' + ctr + '"><h4 class="panel-title accordion-toggle">' + vQuestion + ' </h4></div><div id="collapse' + ctr + '" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body"> ' + vAnswer + '</div></div></div>').appendTo(".panel-group");
   });

   if (pageIndex2 >= pageCount2) {
     $("#loadmore").hide();
   }

   $("#loader").hide();


 }
```

Comment: Remove `UseSubmitBehavior` property from server control and try this `OnClientClick="Search();return false;"`. What does `Search()` method do, does it internally causing page refresh/reload.

Comment: I tried this this stops postback and search function doesnt get data

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal, It was typo is Copy paste. I have updated Code and Fiddle, It is actually `OnClientClick="triggerSearch();"` this function

Comment: Do you want postback as well?

Comment: I want partial post back. I want to show search result without doing a full postback – Learning just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid postback you need to do like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearchQA" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server"
     Text="SEARCH" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="return triggerSearch();" 
     UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
```

and your javascript function should return false.

```
function SearchRecords(vSearch) {
  //your codes
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This made code to work and show the result. But when i click the same search button for another search then nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

If no ASP.NET postback is intended then there is no reason to use an ASP.NET `<asp:Button />` web server control. Use a HTML `<button>` instead.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchQA" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="triggerSearch();">
             SEARCH
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Make sure to specify `type="button"`, otherwise the browser will assume `type="submit"` by default and result in a standard browser postback.

Comment: This is behaving in same manner as ASP button... now pasot back is not happening but result is not also showing

Comment: @Learning you want postback as well?

Comment: I want partial post back. I want to show search result without doing a full postback

Comment: @Learning, please check your browser console for any errors or to debug just how much of your code is being executed.

Comment: @GoranMottram, tried code 'शेखर' it works but i am able to clock button only once. so i am able to search only once. Next time when i search it doesnt do anything

Comment: @Learning, it's tough to tell but I have a feeling it has to do with `pageIndex2++;` incrementing each time a search is performed. It appears the `if` condition straight after will evaluate to false on subsequent calls.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I had fixed it as now i am resetting count each time when search button is click.